# PHONEGAP - Unable to import Certificate - IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, certificate, phonegap-build

I have been working on this problem since noon of yesterday and can't find help anywhere throughout the web.

In Phonegap Build, the IOS Phonegap keys I create always gives this error when building:

Error - Unable to import Certificate - You can fix this [here](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/2.9.0/#googtrans%28en%29)

I have tried recreating multiple .p12 export files from Keychain Access and even tried Revoking and recreating new certificates on apples dev site. I've tried many other things and mostly searched the internet.

I have over 15 hours invested in finding a solution to this issue and feel as though I haven't gained any progress :(

Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: iOS keys/certs are a nightmare, even when using Xcode directly. In order to get help, you're probably going to walk through the specific steps you took in creating the certs and .p12s.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but the certificate that used to worked stopped working on Phonegap Build with `Error - Unable to import Certificate - You can fix this here`. I recreated it but still had the same error. I recreated it again (this time I used a simpler password, avoiding too strange characters) and then it worked. It's not the 1st time I have weird things happening with Apple.

Here is what I do on Win7 64:

I have a CreateKey.bat file as follow

```
openssl genrsa -out %1.key 2048
openssl req -new -key %1.key -out %1.certSigningRequest  -subj "/emailAddress=info@me.com, commonName=me, countryName=me" -config "C:\Software\OpenSSL_098e_x64\openssl.cnf"
```

and a CreateP12.bat file

```
openssl x509 -in %1.cer -inform DER -out %1.pem -outform PEM
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey %1.key -in %1.pem -out %1.p12
```

1. I run as admin `CreateKey.bat TheNameOfCertifToCreate`
2. Then in https://developer.apple.com in the certificate tab, I say I want to create one. I'm asked to upload a .certSigningRequest, I select the one that was just created. At the end I download the certificate, giving it the name `TheNameOfCertifToCreate.cer`
3. I run as admin `CreateP12.bat TheNameOfCertifToCreate`. It will ask you twice for a the password to associate with the p12. It'll create a `TheNameOfCertifToCreate.p12` that you'll have to upload to Phonegap Build.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick guide for how to sign certificates under Windows.

http://spaceport.io/developers/neo_docs/guides/how_to_get_your_ios_signing_keys_windows.html

This works for me, if you need more help, please let us know the steps you are taking and we can assist further - I'm doing this with provisioning profiles and my iOS dev certificate so it definitely does work.